# Bash script strange pgrep behaviour

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a simple bash script that will toggle `imwheel` between running and not running.

The following code is in `toggle-imwheel.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep imwheel;
then
        # imwheel process found
        echo "Killing imwheel process"
        killall imwheel
else
        # imwheel process not found
        echo "Starting imwheel process"
        imwheel
fi
```

`pgrep` should be returning an exit code of 0 when it has found something and an exit code of 1 when nothing is found. However, it appears that pgrep is finding processes that don't exist. Here is the bash shell output:

```
mrsiliconguy@swift3:~/.imwheel-scripts$ pgrep imwheel <---- notice that no process is running
mrsiliconguy@swift3:~/.imwheel-scripts$ ./toggle-imwheel.sh 
9952 <------ ??????
Killing imwheel process
imwheel: no process found
mrsiliconguy@swift3:~/.imwheel-scripts$ ./toggle-imwheel.sh 
9955
Killing imwheel process
imwheel: no process found
```

Comment: I would expect the smaller `imwheel` to match against the longer `toggle-imwheel`. Maybe change to `toggle-IMwheel` will solve it? Good luck.

Comment: Note that in general, killing processes by hand is bad practice -- on a modern operating system you should be using the process supervision service it provides (launchd on MacOS, systemd on most Linux distros) to check service status, stop and start services.

Comment: That would make this as simple as `if systemctl is-active imwheel; then systemctl stop imwheel; else systemctl start imwheel; fi` (once you've built an `imwheel.service`), and it won't mistakenly kill a process with a name like `imwheel-monitor` or something other than the real target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try if you run `bash toggle-imwheel` your script should work too. 
This is because pgrep will default try to match command name. The name of your script called `foo-imwheel.sh`, when you start it by `./foo-imwheel`, pgrep will find your script self as matched process.

However, if you start it by `bash foo-imwheel` or `sh foo-imwheel`, the command is `sh or bash`. pgrep will not match the script itself.

You can test with `pgrep -l` to list the command in output.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the regex for pgrep to match exactly :

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep '^imwheel$';
then
        # imwheel process found
        echo "Killing imwheel process"
        killall imwheel
else
        # imwheel process not found
        echo "Starting imwheel process"
        imwheel
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, running the script with `sh` works properly... Not entirely sure why.

```
mrsiliconguy@swift3:~/.imwheel-scripts$ pgrep imwheel
mrsiliconguy@swift3:~/.imwheel-scripts$ sh toggle-imwheel.sh 
Starting imwheel process
INFO: imwheel started (pid=10439)
mrsiliconguy@swift3:~/.imwheel-scripts$ pgrep imwheel 
10439
mrsiliconguy@swift3:~/.imwheel-scripts$ sh toggle-imwheel.sh 
10439
Killing imwheel process
mrsiliconguy@swift3:~/.imwheel-scripts$ pgrep imwheel
mrsiliconguy@swift3:~/.imwheel-scripts$
```

Comment: Does it also work properly with `bash toggle-imwheel.sh`? If so, the difference is that `pgrep` is no longer matching your toggle script as a program name to start, and `killall` is no longer matching it as a program name to kill, because the program name is seen as `sh` or `bash` instead of `toggle-imwheel.sh`.

Comment: (btw, in general, it's bad practice to use extensions on executable scripts at all; just call it `toggle-imwheel` with no extension, and then your extension doesn't become inaccurate when some later-you rewrites it in Python -- and isn't inaccurate in the first place because you used a `#!/bin/bash` shebang with a `.sh` extension instead of a `.bash` extension). See also the essay [Commandname extensions considered harmful](http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/), and relevant #bash IRC factoid history at http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh.

Comment: ...anyhow, if `bash toggle-imwheel.sh` does also fix it, then the answer by @Philippe is a simpler/more-targeted fix (though I don't recommend using `pgrep` or `pkill` for this purpose at all, and stand by the suggestion to use your operating system's process-supervision mechanism instead).